# Cakephp Finnish language not coming out properly

Tags: php, cakephp

In Cake, I have this issue with Finnish language not displaying properly. I have set utf encoding in config.php, charset output in default.ctp and also config in core.php

Is there a reason why it's not coming out properly?

To give you an idea the link is below:

http://www.likeslomakkeet.net/petitions/add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you re-import your data to database after changed your database.php and database collations? Try re-adding any commune with special characters like "Hämeenkyrö" and see how it looks like in database.

edit: You could also filter out all communes with "(lakkautettu)" because they no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

Did you also set the database connection to UTF-8 in `database.php`?

For MySQL, that would be:

```
'encoding' => 'utf8' // no hyphen
```

Comment: MySQL database **and** database tables set to `utf8_general/unicode_ci` collation?